# WordPress panel is not loading after plugin activated with error: HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

when i try to activate `Yoast Seo Plugin`, my WordPress panel stop loading and the browser displays: `HTTP ERROR 500`.

I checked my error_log file and there was this error:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_generate_theme_initialize' not found or invalid function name in .../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
```

which the line 286 is:

```
if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
            } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                $value = call_user_func_array($the_['function'], $args ); //Line 286
            } else {
                $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
            }
```

I don't it's  related to my problem or not cause the time of the error was right but when I delete the error_log file and refresh my WordPress panel the error_log file didn't show any errors...

In case you need my `function.php`, here is 20 first lines of my code:

```
<?php
add_action('wordpress_theme_initialize', 'wp_generate_theme_initialize');
// function wp_generate_theme_initialize(  ) {
    //   echo "Designed by Mehdi Karimi";
// }
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'setup_theme_after_run', 999);
function setup_theme_after_run() {
    if(has_action( 'wordpress_theme_initialize',  'wp_generate_theme_initialize')) {
        add_action('wordpress_theme_initialize', 'wp_generate_theme_initialize');
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'setup_theme_after_run_footer', 1);
function setup_theme_after_run_footer() {
   if(did_action('wordpress_theme_initialize' )) {
       add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_generate_theme_initialize');
   }
}
```

Here is my website: [MegaTips](https://megatips.ir)
Thanks for your time... ♥

Comment: The problem is your function.php. You have commented out the function `wp_generate_theme_initialize` but are still calling it in the first line. So either remove/comment that line or do not uncomment the function. This is also what the error says: `function 'wp_generate_theme_initialize' not found`

Comment: That would be responsible for the error in the error log, but wouldn't throw a 500 error and break the site. If a relatively popular plugin like Yoast is causing this error, then there's either a conflict with another plugin, or you're running an out of date version of PHP.

Comment: @kraftner ok i uncomment that but still the my panel not loading after activating yoast

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes I guess yoast got conflict with W3 Total Cache, cause when I deactivate W3, my panel loads fine with yoast working fine...

Comment: @JacobPeattie and by the way when yoast is activated and w3 deactivated, my panel loads but the theme customizer won't load...